# Where is Wordnet owl files

Tags: benchmarking, rdf, owl, ontology, wordnet

I downloaded Wordnet2.0full set.  But, i need owl files

I Tried http://mowl-power.cs.man.ac.uk:8080/converter/ Manchester Converter for rdf to owl converting.

however, It doesn't work on company device

How to use Wordnet Test??

I need schema owl file and data owl files

[image]

Comment: Given that one of the files is wnfull.rdfs, I wonder if this is an RDF(S) ontology and not an OWL ontology?  Also, _where_ did you get these files?  The [WordNet old versions page](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/old-versions/) says that you shouldn't use 2.0 unless you know you need that specific version, but in any case, I don't RDF downloads.  We'll need more information about what you've done so far if we're going to be able to help.

Comment: Joshua Taylor// last working is LUBM test. LUBM generator give me owl schema(univ_bench.owl) and many datafile. Anyway I think cause of the problem is our device. thanks comment Joshua

Comment: A note: don't try to convert files of this size through the converter at http://mowl-power.cs.man.ac.uk:8080/converter/ - I happen to know mowl-power is a Raspberry Pi machine. Way WAY underpowered to convert a hundred megabytes file and still keep up with requests from the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beginning of wnfull.rdfs looks like this:

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:wn20schema="http://www.w3.org/2006/03/wn/wn20/schema/"
  xml:base="http://www.w3.org/2006/03/wn/wn20/schema/"
    xml:lang="en-US">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="">
```

So it looks like it's already an OWL ontology, although with an rdfs file extension. You should be able to load it as an OWL ontology regardless of the extension - or you can change the extension to .owl if you prefer.